# Get next N rows starting from any row SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm querying an SQLite database and want to get the next n rows starting from any row. I know that `SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TABLENAME` will return the top 10 results but is there a way to do it say starting from rownumber 20 and selecting the next 10 results after that?

I need to edit this query...

```
 public Soul[] SoulList(string row, string itemsPerRow)
        {
            Soul[] rval = null;
            using (var sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT * FROM SOULS"))
            {
                rval = GetSouls(sqlCommand);
            }

            return rval;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses.  For example, to get records 10 starting at position 10 you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM SOULS LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

If you want to also order the results by a column `col` then you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM SOULS ORDER BY col LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```